# How do I print unicode with 5 characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to make a discord bot in python and use Unicode for emojis using "\u", for example:

```
await ctx.send("\u1F389")
```

This should be the confetti popper emoji, but I've noticed it has 5 characters instead of the usual 4 (1F389) and clearly, Python did too, it prints Ἰ9, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u` must be a 4-digit code.  `\U` uses 8-digit codes:

```py
>>> print('\U0001F389')
```

You can also use `chr`:

```py
>>> print(chr(0x1f389))
```

Or look up and use by name:

```py
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name(chr(0x1f389))
'PARTY POPPER'
>>> print('\N{PARTY POPPER}')
```

Answer (score 2):

The Python notation for non-BMP Unicode code points uses `\U` instead of `\u` and eight hex digits.

```py
await ctx.send("\U0001F389")
```

Comment: Pretty sure this must be a duplicate, but could not quickly locate an existing question about this.